# Augmented Reality using vuforia/unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I'm working on an augmented reality app. I have to scan a QR code on a huge sculpture and display virtual information/images/videos all around it (so when I hold the cell phone, I'll have to go around the sculpture to see the displayed info on each side).

So far, using Vuforia, QR code scanning was successful using the QR code image as an image target. However, the displayed virtual object does not stay in place when I move around; it changes positions and sometimes disappears (Even with extended tracking). I want it to stay fixed in the same place after scanning, no matter how I move my camera. How can I do that?

Adding to that, is there a way to display virtual objects around a sculpture, that appear after scanning a single QR code? So I will just have to go around the sculpture to see them?